# Как безопасно реализовать

Tags: сервер, безопасность

У меня есть сайт, он основан на работе с другим сайтом (сайт В).
Авторизация происходит в CURL (API нету).
Поэтому Cookie всех авторизаций моих юзеров на сервере в txt файлах, которые потом читает Curl при повторной авторизации.

Как можно огородить файлы от стороннего доступа?

Comment: Давайте попробуем посмотреть на проблему с другой стороны. Как посторонний человек мог бы получить несанкционированный доступ к этим файлам?

Comment: А может, стоит пересмотреть способ хранения cookies? Что натолкнуло вас на мысль хранить их в файлах, а не в базе данных? Ограничения хостинга? Или есть какие-то реальные преимущества такого подхода?

Comment: через htaccess запретить доступ всем, кроме сервера, к той директории, в которой лежит файл